# How to Make a mutually excusive select query in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql, and I need to write a query for a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE TESTS
PATH_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Day DATE NOT NULL,
    Direction varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    D_ID int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES Drivers(D_ID),
);
INSERT INTO TESTS(PATH_ID,Day,Direction,D_ID)
VALUES (1,'2021-02-01' ,'Right',001),
(2,'2021-02-01' ,'Left',002),
(3,'2021-02-02','Right',002),
```

What I need to do is write a query that shows drivers (D_ID) who have ONLY ever gone Right (Direction), and show The D_ID, the Day, and all the times the driver went right.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tests t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tests t2
                  where t2.d_id = t.d_id and t2.direction <> 'Right'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use not in

```
select a.* from Tests a where D_ID not in (
select D_ID from Tests where direction <>'Right'
)
```